# AutomationElement in UWP apps

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, ui-automation

I am doing some experiments with UI Automation in UWP apps and I wonder, whether is possible to use following code in UWP app ([Getting a Handle to a button in another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209746/getting-a-handle-to-a-button-in-another-window/24210814#24210814)).

```
var hwnd = FindWindowByCaption((IntPtr)0, "App1");

AutomationElement lync = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
AutomationElement optionsButton = lync.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "something"));
((InvokePattern)optionsButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();
```

If I add "correct" references to my UWP project

- UIAutomationClient
- UIAutomationTypes

I am getting following error.

```
Cannot find type System.SystemException in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary.
```

I completely understand that I simply cannot do it this way (adding those references to UWP projects). Is there any other possible way how to do it or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandboxing of apps in the UWP model means that this isn't possible.

If you have a strong reason for needing to do this then make a suggestion (with your reason for needing it--it helps you be more persuasive) on https://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The OP is receiving an error after adding a reference (that cannot be used in a UWP project), i.e. a compile-time error. This is not a runtime restriction, and UI Automation is well supported for UWP applications. If you don't believe me, fire up calc.exe and have a look around using the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool.

Comment: @IInspectable the process isolation part of the sandboxing means one UWP process can't see into other apps. The error looks like a runtime one to me. But it's created because compile time restrictions mean you can't include a reference to the DLL that contains the FindWindow method in a UWP. I'm very familiar with tools like Inspect but it seems that the OP wants to create a UWP that does something similar in a UWP but that's not currently possible. (Even though Insect can query UWP apps)

Comment: I overlooked, that the OP is trying to run UI Automation **from** a UWP application. While it is possible for a UWP application to register events, patterns, or properties for use by UI Automation, it cannot itself drive another application. I'd still argue, that the error the OP is observing is not a runtime error, but rather a failed attempt to resolve a dependent type reference.